# Android Media Player Restart Audio After Calling Stop

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I'm able to stream audio and stop it without any problem, but when I try to start it again after stop, it doesn't start and I get an IllegalState exception.

Here is what I'm doing:

Start Playing

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Stop Playing

```
mediaPlayer.stop
```

Now, if I want to start playing again the same media, what will I have to do?

*PATH is the URL of a continuous running radio station.

Comment: Can you post your code for understanding?

Comment: Fixed. I wasn't calling reset after stop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this:

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 41):

In case you don't have access to the data source in the current scope, you can do:

```
mp.pause();
mp.seekTo(0);
```

Then when you do

```
mp.start();
```

play will start from the beginning again.

I needed this because I had a button that toggled playing. I had a togglePlayer method in which the datasource was out of scope.

Comment: Great and simple!

Answer (score 5):

you can check the state diagram of mediaplayer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
after the mediaplayer stopped, must call prepare, when prepared,and then you can call start method.