# Android Media Player doesn't play after app has been left for a while in the background

Tags: android, bundle, android-mediaplayer

Bit of a strange one this and I can't work out what's happening.

When I launch my app (a game) the music starts playing.  I have a button which turns the music on and off.  The settings are saved to **shared prefs** so they are retained.

All works well, you can press the home key, re-invoke the app, leave it in the background while doing other things etc.  However, if the app is left in the background for a while (say, overnight), and then re-invoked.  Everything works apart from the music.

You can go into the main menu, hit the 'music on/off' button multiple times, but get nothing.

The only way to start the music is to kill the app (or exit correctly, ie, press the 'back' key from the main menu) and then relaunch it so everything is re-created from scratch.

I've confirmed that the 'music' object is still valid and the 'music on/off' button presses *are* being registered.

Has anyone has similar issues with Media Player?  I can't work out what I am (or am not doing) to cause this.

**Code**

This is my media player class:

```
public class MusicMan implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

MediaPlayer musicPlayer;

MusicMan(Context myContext){

    musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(myContext, R.raw.music);
    musicPlayer.setVolume(.6f, .6f);


}

public void listener(){};


public void start(){

    musicPlayer.setLooping(true);
    musicPlayer.start();

}

public void stop(){

    musicPlayer.stop();

}

public void pause(){

    musicPlayer.pause();        
}


public int getPos(){

    return musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition();        
}


public void skipTo(int position){

    musicPlayer.seekTo(position);

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {

}


}
```

And then I simply crate an object like so:

```
MusicMan music = new MusicMan(view.getContext());
```

And then I just start and stop the music using the methods in the MusicMan class:

```
music.start();
```

Comment: WHen you start your app and turn on the music after click home button the music still played ?

Comment: Hi @Abdellah, yes but only if the app isn't left too long.  If I press home, then leave it for a long time (like over night or at least for a few hours), then go back into it, there is no music and I have to kill the app and re-start it from scratch.

Comment: so you must use services

Comment: @Abdellah, please elaborate, why would I want to use a service?  I don't want the music to play while the app is in the background.  My understanding is that you only need to use a service if you *do* want it to continue playing in the background (while your app isn't on the screen).

Comment: you are saying : if the app is left in the **background** for a while .. so you need to play music when the app are in the background

Comment: No, I think you mis-read my question, @Abdellah "However, if the app is left in the background for a while (say, overnight), and then re-invoked. Everything works apart from the music." meaning if the user presses the home key to do other things, and then decides to go back into the app.......:-)

Comment: yeah yeah excuse me .. i am poor english man, hope this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486828/android-media-player-restart-audio-after-calling-stop

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
musicPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

Use this where you set new MediaPlayer player. It sets the wake lock to MediaPlayer and don't let CPU go sleep till you yourself didn't kill or stop application.