# Stop button is not working.play and pause is working but as soon as I click on the stop button play and pause button also stop playing

Tags: android

I am a beginner and I have created a simple media player but the problem is that the stop button is not working. Play and pause is working good but the problem is is only with the stop button. After tapping on the stop button the music stops but play and pause stop working.

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mymediaplayer;
    AudioManager myaudiomanager;

    public void playme(View view) {
        mymediaplayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseme(View view) {
        mymediaplayer.pause();
    }

    public void stopme(View view) {
        mymediaplayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music);
        myaudiomanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int max=myaudiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
             int progress=myaudiomanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        SeekBar volumerocker=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volume);
        volumerocker.setMax(max);
        volumerocker.setProgress(progress);
        volumerocker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                myaudiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,i,0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If the play and pause stops playing after you press the stop button, then the media player is really stopped hardly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Media Player Restart Audio After Calling Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486828/android-media-player-restart-audio-after-calling-stop)

Comment: Check several answers here as well -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563729/media-player-start-stop-start

Comment: no that was not the answer of my question

Comment: I had solved my problem for myself. no need to help.

Comment: Great. Share the answer here for helping future developers.