# Created simple media player but after clicking each button five or six time it stop playing

Tags: android

I have created a simple media player. After clicking each button five or six times, it stops playing sound. But the app is not crashing and not showing any error. The app is playing sound without any problem at the first time. Plus, in my function where I have created `onClick` method, can I apply the stop or pause function to stop the previous playing sound?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mymediaplayer;
AudioManager myaudiomanager;
public void playone(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}
public void playtwo(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.two);
    mymediaplayer.start();

}
public void playthree(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.three);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}
public void playfour(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.four);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}
public void playfive(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.five);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}
public void playsix(View view)
{
    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.six);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myaudiomanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int max=myaudiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int   progress=myaudiomanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SeekBar volume=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    volume.setMax(max);
    volume.setProgress(progress);
    volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            myaudiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,i,0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should release media player before starting to play new item. I did change `playone` as example:

```
public void playone(View view)
{
    releaseMediaPlayer(mymediaplayer);//release previous player if there are any

    mymediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.one);
    mymediaplayer.start();
}


void releaseMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mPlayer){
   if(mPlayer!=null)
   {
     mPlayer.release();
   }
}
```

Comment: where should i do that

Comment: can anyone explain me releaseMediaPlayer function

Comment: @AshadNasim Whenever you start media player inside your application, before going to the next music you should release previous playing media player and then start next music. I brought `releaseMediaPlayer` for convenience so you can call it inside all of your functions `playone` to `playsix`. this function check if current mediaplayer variable is not null (which may happen when you are going to play for first time and there is no player running so there is not need to stop and release it) and if it is not null,  then it will call `mplayer.relase()`.

Comment: Ok, i understood .can you give an answer to my another question related to the same topic.kindly reply me.That question is also like that. here is the link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104297/stop-button-is-not-working-play-and-pause-is-working-but-as-soon-as-i-click-on-t?noredirect=1#comment85213761_49104297